# Return success of Google user login from a Java method

Tags: java, oauth

We need to check if the credentials of a google user is correct or not in a Java program.
The Java program will get the google username and password, should check if the user name and password matches or not. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you are aware that Google also has a magnificent web search engine. I'd recommend using that. Then if you have got a specific question, or an error, we'll surely be able to help...